# RemoteIO Unit remove background noise

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit, remoteio

Is there a way to remove background noise from audio samples coming from microphone(RemoteIO Unit) like Apple does it in AirPods during phone call? Which AudioUnit is most effective to achieve this?

Comment: Not the way Apple does it, as iOS uses input data from multiple microphones for noise reduction, which RemoteIO does not allow.

Comment: Ok, but how does it do noise cancellation with AirPods -- getting data from both AirPods?

Comment: Each AirPod is reported to have more than 1 microphone hidden inside.  Unknown whether the multiple microphones on the iPhone are also used in conjunction.